# How to save a index built using ScaNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nearest-neighbor

I am wondering how can we save the index built using [ScaNN tool](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann).

```
start = time.time()

searcher = scann.scann_ops_pybind.builder(normalized_dataset, 10, "dot_product").tree(
    num_leaves=2000, num_leaves_to_search=100, training_sample_size=250000).score_ah(
    2, anisotropic_quantization_threshold=0.2).reorder(100).build()

end = time.time()
```

print("Index Latency (ms): {:8.4f}".format( 1000*(end - start)) )

Answer (score 1):

Answer is mentioned in this [GitHub issue.](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/issues/355)

Here are the working syntax for scann 1.2

```
INDEX_DIR = './index'
os.makedirs(INDEX_DIR, exist_ok=True)
searcher.serialize(INDEX_DIR) # store the scann_module 

another_searcher = scann.scann_ops_pybind.load_searcher(INDEX_DIR)
neighbors, distances = another_searcher.search_batched(dataset, final_num_neighbors=25)
```